# MPU6050 returns HAL_BUSY in the second read attempt

Tags: stm32, i2c, stm32cubeide

I am trying to connect to MPU6050 from STM32F103C8T6 microcontroller. For this purpose, I use STM32CubeIDE programming environment. The initialization process succeeds and I can read the module data in the first cycle, but when I try to read the module data the second time, I get a HAL_BUSY response. What could be the problem?
this is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();

  while (MPU6050_Init(&hi2c1) == 1);
  while (1)
  {
      MPU6050_Read_All(&hi2c1, &MPU6050);
      HAL_Delay (100);
  }
}

uint8_t MPU6050_Init(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2Cx) {
    uint8_t check;
    uint8_t Data;

    // check device ID WHO_AM_I

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, WHO_AM_I_REG, 1, &check, 1, i2c_timeout);

    if (check == 104)  // 0x68 will be returned by the sensor if everything goes well
    {
        // power management register 0X6B we should write all 0's to wake the sensor up
        Data = 0;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, PWR_MGMT_1_REG, 1, &Data, 1, i2c_timeout);

        // Set DATA RATE of 1KHz by writing SMPLRT_DIV register
        Data = 0x07;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, SMPLRT_DIV_REG, 1, &Data, 1, i2c_timeout);

        // Set accelerometer configuration in ACCEL_CONFIG Register
        // XA_ST=0,YA_ST=0,ZA_ST=0, FS_SEL=0 -> � 2g
        Data = 0x00;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, ACCEL_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1, i2c_timeout);

        // Set Gyroscopic configuration in GYRO_CONFIG Register
        // XG_ST=0,YG_ST=0,ZG_ST=0, FS_SEL=0 -> � 250 �/s
        Data = 0x00;
        HAL_I2C_Mem_Write(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, GYRO_CONFIG_REG, 1, &Data, 1, i2c_timeout);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void MPU6050_Read_All(I2C_HandleTypeDef *I2Cx, MPU6050_t *DataStruct) {
    uint8_t Rec_Data[14];
    int16_t temp;

    // Read 14 BYTES of data starting from ACCEL_XOUT_H register

    HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(I2Cx, MPU6050_ADDR, ACCEL_XOUT_H_REG, 1, Rec_Data, 14, i2c_timeout);

    DataStruct->...    
}
```

Comment: If so, the HAL is busy then. Likely problem is the HAL being used incorrectly. Post the code to get an answer.

Comment: That can't be the full code, and the HAL should not end up BUSY unless the first round has some error and chip never allows bus to be released so I2C peripheral stays busy. Or, something other weirdness is going on after the first read which corrupts the memory. But your code never checks for the I2C operation to fail or succeed. Have you debugged where exactly the HAL ends up returning something else than OK?

Comment: This is the body of the code I'm using. If you want more details I can send that too. When I debug the code, the first time the HAL_I2C_Mem_Read command returns HAL_OK, but the second time I execute it immediately without any additional work, it returns HAL_BUSY.

Comment: You are not limited to debugging when the HAL returns with HAL_BUSY, you are also able to debug where in the HAL and why it returns you HAL_BUSY, as there are multiple options where and why it can do that. It is very well possible that the code you don't show corrupts stack or memory so what happens if you don't do anything else than read 14 bytes in a loop in main?

Comment: I noticed that if I read the module information with a buffer length of one byte, there is no problem, but if I consider the length of the buffer more than one byte, this problem occurs.

Comment: Which may indicate a stack or other memory corruption issue in the code. Impossible to say without seeing the code. Stack size may be important, especially if you run an RTOS with many tasks, and pre-emptive RTOS may go handle other tasks while the I2C has important timings to take care of.